# Get ID of highest property

Tags: javascript, json

How can I return the ID with the highest 'number' associated with it?

```
items = [
   {id: 4, number: 45}, 
   {id: 5, number: 49}, 
   {id: 7, number: 44}
]
```

Comment: what if more than one have the same value? what have you tried? what does not work? why the upvote?

Comment: So far I just get the max 'number', then I do a .find() with that max number as the parameter. It works but i feel there could be a better way. And in this case that I need, equal numbers don't matter. It just needs to return 1 of the Ids with the highest 'number'

Comment: That's the correct way to do this, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `find` and `every()`

```js
const items = [
   {id: 4, number: 45}, 
   {id: 5, number: 49}, 
   {id: 7, number: 44}
]

const res = items.find(x => items.every(a => a.number <= x.number)).id
console.log(res)
```

```js
const items = [
   {id: 4, number: 45}, 
   {id: 5, number: 49}, 
   {id: 7, number: 44}
]

const res = items.sort((a,b) => b.number - a.number)[0].id
console.log(res)
```

The above solution has O(n ^ 2) time complexity. If you want linear time complexity you can first find max number using `Math.max` and then use `find`

```js
const items = [
   {id: 4, number: 45}, 
   {id: 5, number: 49}, 
   {id: 7, number: 44}
]

const max = Math.max(...items.map(x => x.number));
const res = items.find(x => x.number === max).id;
console.log(res)
```

Comment: That's just a more unreadable way of sorting the array and getting the first element. I'll give you points for creativity though.

Comment: @ChrisG Yea I agree. I have added another solution with kind of better way ig.

Comment: That's exactly what OP is already doing though :) This is more of a codereview question without code to review apparently.

Comment: Thank you, your second way is actually exactly how I already did it. Wasn't sure if it was the best way to do it but thank you for the vote of confidence on that.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah sorry about that, just didn't want to give any sort of bias' and wanted to see a broad spectrum of solutions to a simple question.

Comment: @surpol Oh sorry I didn't read the comments. BTW are you worried about time complexity in this particular case our you are just wanting a short code

Comment: @MaheerAli Both actually

Comment: this answer has more than one necessary loop. for example the last with finding max requires two loops, the first for mapping the value and the second to find max. then you take a thir loop to find the object.

Comment: @NinaScholz You are right but it looks cleaner I guess.

Comment: @MaheerAli, really? O_o

Comment: @NinaScholz This is my way of solving this one. I didn't wanted to just copy other two answers. I wanted to give some different ways of solving the problem. Your solution seems better in case of performance and also looks clean. But IDK why user accepted mine.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `reduce`

```js
const items = [
   {id: 4, number: 45}, 
   {id: 5, number: 49}, 
   {id: 7, number: 44}
]


const max = items.reduce((max , item) => {
    if(max.number < item.number){
        return item;
    }
    return max;
});

console.log(max.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Both approaches require only a single loop to obtain the desired object(s).**

If the data contains only one max `number`, then you could reduce th array and take only the one object with the greater `number`.

```js
const
    items = [{ id: 4, number: 45 }, { id: 5, number: 49 }, { id: 7, number: 44 }],
    maxItem = items.reduce((a, b) => a.number > b.number ? a : b);

console.log(maxItem.id);
```

Approach for having more than one item with max `number`.

```js
const
    items = [{ id: 4, number: 45 }, { id: 5, number: 49 }, { id: 6, number: 49 }, { id: 7, number: 44 }],
    maxItems = items.reduce((max, item, i) => {
        if (!i || max[0].number < item.number) return [item];
        if (max[0].number === item.number) max.push(item);
        return max;
    }, []);

console.log(maxItems);
```